# is it possible to user .so libraries from another device?

Tags: android, embedded-linux

I have a Samsung s5pv210 based devkit runs android 2.2. I've modified it's
source, especially external/webkit, frameworks to support
my language and built it.

now, is it possible to use these modified libraries on same s5pv210 based mid device i want to buy on market? ( i want to replace these files on that mid i will buy, because
it doesn't support my language ).

ps : chinese tablet manufactories not so friendly with GPL and rarely release their GPL sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it depends on the same architecture, kernel and libc versions, yes

Comment: thanks, could you please point to me any websites/tutorial or some details on this matter? about this compatibility/dependency issue?